# Find textbox in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid which contains four columns.

So from this datagrid on the C# side, i want to find the particular textbox with name = "headBox"

How I go about doing this? my xaml for the column goes as below. This section is within Datagrid.Columns which is inside the datagrid tag with name = dgrid

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBox Name="HeadBox"/>
        </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use

```
DataGridRow row = myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex
(myDataGrid.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;

var i = 0; /// Specify your column index here.
```

**EDIT**

```
TextBox ele = ((ContentPresenter)(myDataGrid.Columns[i].GetCellContent(row))).Content as TextBox;
```

Comment: No there is a FindByName method somewhere which fits better as does not depend on column index. I am on mobile now I cant try it out...

Comment: `FindByName` cannot work on `DataGridColumn`s Template just like that as for that you would need to supply a datagrid cell instance.

Comment: @AngelWPF hmm apparently I get a null pointer exception. the textbox ele is always empty. I tried to get the type of  myDataGrid.Columns[i].GetCellContent(row). it gives me type content presenter

Comment: @AngelWPF when i use DataGridRow row
         = myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex
                 (myDataGrid.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;, it always give me an out of bounds exception, the selected index is always 0xffffff, i use this though DataGridRow row = dgrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as DataGridRow;, but the textbox is always null

Comment: @AngelWPF Thanks! I got it already. I used your edited code and i got what i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="ClientDomain"   Width="130" >    
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>    
<DataTemplate>    
<TextBox x:Name="directionColumnTextBlock"  Text="{Binding Path=ClientDomain,Mode=TwoWay}"/>    
<DataTemplate.Triggers>    
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IssReadOnly}" Value="true">    
<Setter TargetName="directionColumnTextBlock"  Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true"  />    
</DataTrigger>    
</DataTemplate.Triggers>    
</DataTemplate>    
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>    
</DataGridTemplateColumn >     


DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex
(dataGrid.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;    

TextBox clientDomain= ((ContentPresenter)(dataGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row))).Content as TextBox
```

Comment: @AngelWPF But, i am seeing clientDomain as null. can u please help me in making it..