# WPF get TextBox Value from datagridtemplatecolumn

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Hello guys I am trying to get TextBox Named "txtQty" value from DataGridTemplateColum

Here is the code, Hope someone Helps me....

.XML

```
     <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridMain">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding PName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Qty" >
                 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                       <DataTemplate >
                             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                  <TextBox x:Name="txtQty"/>                                                                       
                              </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I tried using this code

```
       DataRowView dt = dataGridMain.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

       String value = dt["Qty"].ToString());
```

Comment: Did you try binding its property, like so:  `Text="{Binding Qty}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some struggle I found this solution helpful.....

```
       int i=5; //Set this equal to desired column index.... 
          ContentPresenter myCp = dataGridMain.Columns[i].GetCellContent(dataGridMain.SelectedItem) as ContentPresenter;
        var myTemplate = myCp.ContentTemplate;
        TextBox mytxtbox = myTemplate.FindName("txtQty", myCp) as TextBox;
        MessageBox.Show(mytxtbox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to access the selected row here is the answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/3913791/1449779 also don't forget to bind the text box as DonBoitnott comment

Comment: Actually I am trying to access TextBox from Selected Row.
And text box is in DataGridTemplateColum

Comment: Did you try with TwoWay Binding: <TextBox Text="{Binding Qty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

Comment: Yes dear I did. but this way I only can get cell value not texbox value.....

DataRowView dt = dataGridMain.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

       String value = dt["Qty"].ToString());

Comment: what about this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/7963771/1449779 but you will have to remove the stacklayout or cast first as stacklyout and get the textbox inside

Comment: dpineda: I have followed the method from this link  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7963771/1449779
But it gives the error 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."